# When pulling from a team repo from github, git forces me to make a merge commit, no conflicts

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I've been working with another person on a repo we host at github. Everytime I or he pulls, git forces us to make a merge commit (vim opens up with a commit description), although we were working on different files and there are certainly no conflicts.

Shouldn't new commits be just added without an additional merge-commit?

Answer (score 0):

Think of git's history as a graph. Both your colleague and you are making a new commit that is based on commit A; let's call yours B and his C. History now looks like this:

```
B     C
 \   /
  \ /
   A
```

There are two ways to get that back together. One is merging:

```
   M
  / \
 /   \
B     C
 \   /
  \ /
   A
```

The other is rebasing (e.g. via `git pull --rebase`). In the following example you were the one to rebase:

```
B -- C -- A
```

Both have advantages and disadvantages. As a general rule, rebase works fine if you haven't pushed (or otherwise shared) your commit(s) yet, i.e. you are the only one who has B. If that isn't the case, rebasing will cause very, very annoying issues and you'll be better off merging.

Answer (score 0):

Since each commit records the state of the entire tree a merge needs to be done 
even when the different branches have not modified any of the same files.

Although in this situation it is guaranteed that there won't be any textual 
conflicts, and so git will always be able to automatically merge the changes 
from the different branches, it does not guarantee that there won't be any 
semantic conflicts. For example one branch could modify a method in a library 
to require an additional parameter while the other branch introduces a new call 
to that method; even though the merge won't report any conflicts the resulting 
code will not work without additional changes. Requiring that somebody do an 
explicit merge commit introduces the chance for such a conflict to be caught 
before a non-working commit is made. In practice it is unlikely that anybody 
would check for this type of conflict every time that they do a merge, but if 
merges are only done when there is completed work to merge back into a 
long-running branch it would be less cumbersome to make it a habit to always 
run the test suite after completing a merge.